# Add WMTS layer to QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wmts

How can a WMTS layer be added to QGIS?

I'm trying to add [World Imagery (Wayback 2014-02-20)](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=903f0abe9c3b452dafe1ca5b8dd858b9) to QGIS 3.16.

I'm using the following WMTS link...

```
https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/WMTS/1.0.0/default028mm/MapServer/tile/10/%7Blevel%7D/%7Brow%7D/%7Bcol%7D
```

Here's the error I'm receiving.
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a getcapabilities end point

Comment: You can see the WMTS link on the [World Imagery Page](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=903f0abe9c3b452dafe1ca5b8dd858b9) you just need to scroll down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **QGIS** (3.1x)

use the

> WMTSCapabilities.xml

```
https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to share the source where you found that .xml link, please?

Comment: Google 1st result.. https://www.google.com/search?q=World_Imagery%2FMapServer%2FWMTS%2F1.0.0%2FWMTSCapabilities.xml&oq=World_Imagery%2FMapServer%2FWMTS%2F1.0.0%2FWMTSCapabilities.xml&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8